# Add secured node to the existing Elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I've made a clone of single Elasticsearch node, that was protected by basic security - built-in users with passwords. The clone was added to the Elasticsearch cluster that has certifications for communication between the 3 nodes and enabled basic security - built-in users and passwords.
However, the communication between added clone node and cluster is blocked due to different passwords.
How to reset basic security on the cloned node to avoid blocking communication?

Comment: Have you tried https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/reset-password.html ?

Comment: how exactly did you "clone" the node?